Early recordings of "Once I caught a fish alive"
I’m looking for information on the earliest recording of the children’s song “12345, Once I Caught a Fish Alive.” Despite my efforts, I haven’t been able to find any recordings that date back before the 1980s, and yet this song appears to be several hundred years old.
Does anyone know when the earliest recording was made or have any resources that could help me find this information? It's quite hard to search for because it's often called "1, 2, 3, 4, 5"!
Thanks in advance for your assistance!

"yet this song appears to be several hundred years old": what evidence do you have that it existed before 1980?

@phoog according to Wikipedia, looks like it was first published/recorded in around 1765.

@AndrewT. That publication had the words only, so it could have been associated with a different melody or none at all. The poetic scansion is somewhat different, suggesting that it probably wasn't the melody shown at the top of the Wikipedia article: the 1765 version has lines of 6, 6, 7, and 6 syllables, respectively, while the version with the modern tune has 5, 7, 6, and 7. Of course the melody and placement of syllables can be adjusted somewhat to fit various lines of verse, but I don't see a reasonable way to fit "I caught a hare alive" to the trochaic melody of the second phrase.
